# How to track my memory leak?

Tags: java, lambda, memory-leaks

Basically, here is the situation:

Class `ObjectGenerator` generates tons of objects `X` and put them into an `ArrayList<X>`.

class `ObjectGenerator` is instantiated in the main Thread.

UI Thread (*javaFX*) receive a UI event, and in the lambda handler for that event asks the `ObjectGenerator`'s instance to clear the `ArrayList<X>` and generate/fill it again.

Elsewhere, further in the piece of software, the objects `X` are used in various ways, and, notably, **through many lambdas** (using streams and filters, a lot) which most of the time feed enclosing classes' lists / maps.

Problem is, the amount of generated objects by `ObjectGenerator` just double each time `ObjectGenerator` generate them (although each time, the Lists/Maps are cleared).

After discovering that, I tried to track the memory leak using *VisualVM*, but I could just confirm that the objects are not GC and stayed in `ObjectGenerator`, but not why.

**Bottom line: Can this be likely due to the use of the lambdas** (which each time fills some collection of some kind in the enclosing class) keeping references, Can this be due to the reading being done in the UI Thread and so, keeps somehow references, **or should I just keep looking more "classical" obvious bug** ?

Comment: Don't describe your code, post it in your question, reduced into a [mcve].

Comment: If you do a thread dump you will be able to see where are your X objects locked by strong references, thus explaining why they are not GC'ed

Comment: Thanks, I do understand the need for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. But I think my question was really the bottom line one: Can lambdas introduces by themselves kept references ? I ask because I read about that being a problem (when using the enclosing class's this for instance, which is what I do) on android and being backported to j7 in many places on internet, but I don't really know more about the subject.